# Access Host's log file within docker container

Tags: docker

I want to run `tail -f /var/log/xxx.log` file from existing container, where `/var/log/xxx.log` is a log file inside host.

From docs and with google search, I have found that this is possible with bind mount.

But I couldn't run `tail -f /var/log/xxx.log` . Any advice or proper document about bind mount would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the log directory as a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume) when you run your Docker image, and run your command through Docker that way. An example could be running:
`$ docker run -v /path/to/log:/working your_image tail -f /working/xxx.log`
, where you have to replace `/path/to/log` with `/var/log`, and `your_image` with the name of your image.

The `-v` command requires the path to your folder (within the Host machine) and the location where the path should be mounted to (withing the container). The two locations are place before and after a colon.

In the case above, the path `/path/to/log` is the path to your log folder on your machine, and that location it is mounted to `/working` within the container. Finally, when running the `tail` command, you access your log file through the `/working` directory, which is within the container.

More information about all this can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)!

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ali Nobari, .but I want to do this with a running docker. How can I do this?

Comment: You're welcome @Jasime. For running within a running container, you would use [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/). As long as you have attached the file as a volume as mentioned above, you will be able to access your file through that command. If this is the answer to your question, let me know so I can attach it to my original answer!

Comment: Could I mount bind in this situation?

Comment: @Jasmine, yes you can. If you look at the link I attached at the end of my answer, it will explain the difference between using a volume and a bind mount. You can use whichever one, as you see fit.